# Link 2 Subforms in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vb6, recordset

I have a big form with multiple tab pages
One table is splitted into 2 tab pages

Meants Student_ID, Student_Name in one tab and 
Student_DateOfBirth, Student_Address in another tab
1 : Tom  : 1/5/2005 : Sydney
2 : John : 7/8/2006 : Melbourne
3 : Mike : 3/9/2005 : Perth

The problem is that when I click on Next for the first tab ( that has the ID and Name) nothing happens to the other subform (that has DOB and address)

Sub-Form 1  has 2 : John
Sub-Form 2  has 1/5/2005 : Sydney

is there anyway I can link the 2 subforms so when I go to next record in one sub form the other one does the same

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click Next/Prev buttons on each subforms scroll to the record with the same Student_ID on another subform using subbform code like this:

```
With Me.SubForm2.Form.Recordset.Clone
    .FindFirst "[Student_ID] = " & Me.Student_ID
    Me.SubForm2.Form.Bookmark = .Bookmark
End With
```

Comment: I tried that in Form_Current event, yet nothing happened

Comment: It does compile.. I used this code          Form_G.Form.Recordset.Clone.FindFirst "ID = " & Me.ID

Comment: If you call this code from within Subform1, use Me.Parent.Subform2... Code like this used many times, check references carefully.

Comment: I used SubForm2 directly which is  Form_G, using Me.Form_G or Me.Parent.Form_G is giving error

Answer (score 0):

Although Sergey's answer will work in many cases, you may need an extended solution that works both ways and in all situations:

[Synchronizing Multiple Subforms in Access](http://rdsrc.us/WAKstK)